# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError при добавление копии данных в таблицу БД в цикле for

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Помогите с кодом Python.
Нужно  скопировать записи с БД с заменой одного значения.

Есть код:

```
groups = Group.query.filter(Group.project_id ==    
current_project.id).all()
for group in groups:
    copy_groups = Group()
    copy_groups.project_id = copy_project.id
    copy_groups.name = group.name
    db.session.add(copy_groups)
db.session.commit()
```

Но при запуске кода выбивает ошибку:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
>   (pymysql.err.IntegrityError)
>
> (1062, "Duplicate entry 'owners-60' for
>   key 'group_project_id_index'")
>
> [SQL: 'INSERT INTO `group` (project_id,
>   active, name, manager_id) VALUES (%(project_id)s, %(active)s,
>   %(name)s, %(manager_id)s)'] [parameters: {'manager_id': None,
>   'project_id': 60, 'name': 'owners', 'active': 1}]

Пробовал изменить код:

```
groups = Group.query.filter(Group.project_id ==    
current_project.id).all()
for group in groups:
    copy_groups = Group()
    copy_groups.project_id = copy_project.id
    copy_groups.name = group.name
    db.session.add(copy_groups)
    db.session.commit()
```

Но все равно дает ошибку.

Помогите пожалуйста, как добавить каждую запись с `groups` в базу данных

Comment: ошибка говорит, что дубликаты не разрешены для этой таблицы. Вы что-то другое ожидали?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: если думаете что нашли решение (или оснознали в чём был пробел в понимании), то опубликуйте это как свой ответ, чтобы помочь будущим посетителям из гугла с похожей проблемой. [Это явно поощряется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой код подразумевал копирование проекта, и в коде который я не опубликовал, была строчка

```
copy_project.create_default_groups(current_user, tenant=tenant)
```

из-за которой при копировании осуществлялось дублирование, из-за чего все фейлилось. убрав данную строчку, все заработало корректно.